# What can I do if I got locked out by cphulk?

Tags: permissions, users

Is there any way in Linux to create another user with root rights?
I got locked out by cphulk and I need some other way to log in.

Notice many ways to fix this involve logging in to root or whm.

CPHulk prevented that. So to fix this I need to loggin into root. To loggin into root I need this fixed first. So chicken and eggs problem.

Comment: Please clarify. Why don't you log in as root? Or just log in as another user and then `su` to your original one? Is this a regular user you screwed up or is it root itself? What exactly does "locked out" mean? Does this only affect GUI logins or tty also?

Comment: @terdon Seems that cphulk is a tool to protect against brute force password guessing. See [the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124553/26909). I think this question should be re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

According to the "Fixing a Lockout" instructions in the [cPanel docs](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11%5f30/WHMDocs/CPHulk), you can use WHM to run the following script:

```
/scripts2/doautofixer?autofix=disable_cphulkd
```

Comment: to do so I will need to go to whm or ssh. However I couldn't because cphulk block me.